# C++ Opencv - Any Changes to mat, change the vector used to init mat as well

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector `data` and I create a `cv::mat`:

```
cv::Mat HNorm(this->data.size(), 1, CV_32FC1, this->data.data());
```

Then I normalize `HNorm`'s values:

```
normalize(HNorm, HNorm, 0, 300, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, cv::Mat());
```

The thing is that the same normalization happens to `data` vector. What I want is to be able to work with `HNorm` without affecting `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular constructor you use does not copy the data. It is designed this way for efficiency reasons. This basically just creates the `Mat` headers and changes the internal pointer to point to the supplied `data` array. If you want to not change the underlying data in subsequent operations without affecting the input data array, you need to copy it.

You could `clone` the `Mat` object and this will copy the underlying data. See the docs here:

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ad1c9cc37d66c4e5bd05fae36f62d1cb4

So something like:

```
cv::Mat HNorm(this->data.size(), 1, CV_32FC1, this->data.data());
cv::Mat cloned = HNorm.clone();

// work on the cloned object now
```